# JSON with MVC is not working

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5.2

```
<div id="updatePanel"> </div>
```

My JS script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $("#MyDropDownID").change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("MyMethodToGetList","MyController")",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        loadData(data);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });
            });

            function loadData(data) {
                var tab = $('<table class="myTable"></table>');
                var thead = $('<thead></thead>');
                thead.append('<th>Name</th>');

                tab.append(thead);
                $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                    var trow = $('<tr></tr>');
                    trow.append('<td>' + val.Name + '</td>');
                    tab.append(trow);
                });
                $("tr:odd", tab).css('background-color', '#C4C4C4');
                $("#updatePanel").html(tab);
            };
        });
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
[WebMethod]
public JsonResult MyMethodToGetList()
{
    List<T> list = Class1.ReturnListWithThisParam(1);

    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I'm trying to get a List<> using JSON,..

I'd set a breakpoint in my method, and it works, it retrieves 1 element, but in browser I just got Fail alert, why? What am I doing wrong?

**Other Way (Not works too):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#MyDropDownId').change(function () {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("MyMethodToGetList", "MyController")', function(result) {
                var ddl = $('#MyDropDownId');
                ddl.empty();
                $(result).each(function() {
                    ddl.append(
                    $('<option />', {
                        value: this.Id
                    }).html(this.Name)
                    );
                });
            });
    </script>
```

I was trying to populate my DropDown with JSON:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.MyProperty, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()))
```

My model:

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(SellerMetadata))]
 public partial class Seller
 {    
   public Seller()
    {
        this.SaleRecords = new HashSet<SaleRecord>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public string RG { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdmissionDate { get; set; }
    public Situation Situation { get; set; }
    public Scholarity Scholarity { get; set; }
    public int DeptId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SaleRecord> SaleRecords { get; set; }
}
```

I examined in browser, and I got this error:

```
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   em System.Web.Mvc.Controller.&lt;BeginExecute&gt;b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   em System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   em System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   em System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   em System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   em System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   em System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   em System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   em System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   em System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   em System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   em System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   em System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   em System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   em System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   em System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)
--&gt;
```

Comment: Have you examined the [parameters](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) the error function passes? `error: function(jqhxr, txtStatus, error) { }`

Comment: I made some changes, and now it gives me "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Start here: `@Url.Action("MyMethodToGetList","MyController")` but curious, why you use a 3 line function to `alert(error)`

Comment: Try to manually execute that HTTP request. Internal Server Error is usually about things that go wrong on the server side. Try to debug/log all relevant things and look for any errors your server throws.

Comment: `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error` is catch-all when something goes wrong on the server. You'll need to configure your IIS to pass these details to the browser (turn this off afterwards on a live website) or catch the error with the debugger.

Comment: Watch the network request with the browser's debug console which often gives you much more details about what's going wrong.

Comment: I did, it isn't joining in success function, after success function line, he goes to error line.

Comment: @TimHallman "start here" what? I've changed that function.

Comment: Try `return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`

Comment: Already tried. Let me update more once. (I tried with by another way)

Comment: You'll need to find out more details about the Internal Server Error. Step through (F10 and F11) with the Visual Studio debugger if you have to until you find out these details. Examine and show the network response from the browser's debug network monitor. Until you find these details everyone is just guessing.

Comment: I can't debug on visual studio, I follow the steps in MS documentantion (to allow debug by changing options in IE, but I can't) :/ I was trying in the browser but it's horrible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79230/discussion-between-jasen-and-developer033).

Comment: Remove this from the 2nd to last line of your JS:  `});` it's extra.

Comment: Yes, it's because I was using another thing.. but it's not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the error:
I added it in my controller method:

```
myContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
     $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '/yourController/yourMethod',
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data) {
                      alert('success');
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert('fail');
                        }
                    });

public ActionResult yourMethod()
        {
          return Json("1", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```